# Why am I getting following pack installation errors for STM32F103C8T6 in Keil v5?

Tags: arm, microcontroller, stm32, keil

I am using Keil v5 compiler and have STM32F103C8T6 development board. When I try to install it's related packs in pack installer, I get following error i.e. cannot create temp folder and cannnot compile svd files.

[image]

Due to which the target is not  created. How to resolve this?

Note: I have disabled my antivirus and using 32 bit Windows 7 ultimate OS.

Comment: Are you running Keil as Administrator?

Comment: @A.R.C. Yes I am running keil as administrator. Also ,I tried to install previous packs but same result. I have formatted my c drive ,installed WINDOWS 7 ultimate setup Then I reinstalled keil too but no change at all.

Comment: @A.R.C. I removed packs and tried reinstalling them (no other changes at all) and somehow they got installed without any error. ;-) . But I don't know how it happened